# How to send php value to modal

Tags: php, modal-dialog

I have a query that returns a row of values

```
    <?php
    $chapter_title = $story_data['chapter_title'];
```

and i have an href link that shows a modal when clicked

```
    echo "<a href='#deleteModal'  name='$chapter_title' >delete chapter</a>";
```

which shows

```
    echo "<div id='deleteModal' class='modalDialog'>
                <div>
                    <h3>Delete Chapter Confirmation </h3><h3 style = 'color:red'> $chapter_title</h3><hr>
                    <div style='display:inline-block;width:auto%'>
                        <text>You are about to delete this chapter. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! <br />Do you still want to continue?</text>
                        <br><br>
                        <div id='create_btn'><a href=''>Delete</a></div>
                        <div id='cancel_btn'><a href=''>Cancel</a></div>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>";
    ?>
```

but i am having a problem in displaying the correct $chapter_title. Even when i click the delete button of the second row, it still shows the title of the first row. Please help me on what to do.

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI?

Comment: Once a modal is created, it must be destroyed before being called again.

Comment: i am not using any. and how to destroy a modal?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<h3 style = 'color:red'> $chapter_title</h3>
```

Try echoing the content

```
<h3 style = 'color:red'><?php echo $chapter_title; ?></h3>
```

Comment: so sorry. the modal is inside an echo. but still nothing changes

Comment: can you see the content in page source?

Comment: yes, i can see the content. I can see the <h3>Delete Chapter Confirmation </h3><h3 style = 'color:red'>Edit Chapter 1</h3><hr> and the <h3>Delete Chapter Confirmation </h3><h3 style = 'color:red'>Edit Chapter 2</h3><hr> but in my page, i can see only Delete Chapter Confirmation Edit Chapter 1 whenever i click the delete and even though i am intending to delete Edit Chapter 2

Comment: Try using only one h3, just for checking

Comment: i did it but nothing changed with the chapter title

Answer (score 0):

Correction

```
<a href='#deleteModal'  name='<?php echo $chapter_title; ?>' >delete chapter</a>
```

Comment: they are all inside php

Comment: Okay nevermind then. What javascript plugin are you using to show the modal dialog?

Comment: i did not use any. The <div id='deleteModal' class='modalDialog'> only shows when i clicked the delete href button

Comment: i don't use one. i have been browsing for js that will open my div pop but i can't understand. Any way to do this?